# Process malformed JSON string in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to process a log from Symphony using Pandas, but have some trouble with a malformed JSON which I can't parse.
An example of the log :

```
'{id:46025,
work_assignment:43313=>43313,
declaration:<p><strong>Bijkomende interventie.</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<p>H&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong><em>Vaststellingen.</em></strong></p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong><em>CV. </em></strong>De.</p>=><p><strong>Bijkomende interventie.</strong></p>\r\n\r\n<p>He&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong><em>Vaststellingen.</em></strong></p>\r\n\r\n<p><strong><em>CV. </em></strong>De.</p>,conclusions:<p>H&nbsp;</p>=><p>H&nbsp;</p>}'
```

What is the best way to process this?
For each part (id/work_assignment/declaration/etc) I would like to retrieve the old and new value (which are separated by "=>").

Comment: That doesn't look like json at all.

Comment: It is a JSON-style log, but doesn't comply with the json-definition indeed. The declaration and conclusions part hold HTML-markup

Comment: Read it line by line, remove the `{}`, split on  `:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
def clean(my_log):
    my_log.replace("{", "").replace("}", "")  # Removes the unneeded { }
    my_items = list(my_log.split(","))        # Split at the comma to get the pairs
    my_dict = {}

    for i in my_items:
        key, value = i.split(":")             # Split at the colon to separate the key and value
        my_dict[key] = value                  # Add to the dictionary
    return my_dict
```

Function returns a Python dictionary, which can then be converted to JSON using a serializer if needed, or directly used.

Hope I helped :D

Comment: You don't know whether `:`, `,` and `{}` can be present in the log, even escaped.

Comment: I would assume that since it's the delimeter, it won't be used in the log itself. Regardless, if the docs mention the escaping format, it would be trivial to ignore the escaped characters.

Comment: Your assumption is weak - you simply don't know. Serialized data normally don't have constraints like the one you mentioned - this is why escape characters are a common concept. I did not downvote because your solution is valid (with limitations I'm pointing out). I'm mentioning it because handling escape characters might be trivial for you, but OP finds it non trivial to handle this log format even without taking care of escape characters. Your answer is still good.